# Rejected flag mix up

Tags: support, flags

I suspect there were multiple flags on the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19967245/webpage-displays-incorrectly-on-different-resoltions-due-to-incorrect-css) and my flag was declined with the response to a different flag:

[image]

I was flagging in hopes of getting a bounty question closed, not in response to downvotes.

Comment: You're aware that moderators can't selectively decline & approve flags (on the same post), right?

Comment: We can only type one decline reason and it applies to all the flags. Hopefully the flag system revamp will be done soon! (The other flag was complaining about downvotes on the post, obviously.)

Comment: @Mat So... If they need to decline one flag on a post they have to decline all flags on that post with the same decline notice? That seems... kind of broken.

Comment: Welp. I marked the flags as helpful *just so* this wouldn't happen but hey, guess someone beat me to it.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Should that one have been closed or not? It seems to have a few problems, am I just being too harsh?

Comment: It could use quite a bit of narrowing down (see @animuson's comment on the question), but it is quite well-explained as it is, and I'm not really inclined to go through the trouble of removing the bounty just to close it given the effort the OP has clearly invested in it.

Comment: Sounds related to the issue I brought up a few months ago: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195264/declined-flag-but-accepted-in-practice. Especially this answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/195266/205473

Comment: Guess we'll have to compound decline reasons